# Uninstall Windows Store App from tablet

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, windows-rt, microsoft-surface

Yesterday I installed an alarm clock app from the Store onto my Windows Surface tablet. Now I would like to uninstall the app, but I cannot find how to do so.

How do I uninstall an app that I installed from the Store?

Comment: Right click and select then `uninstall` option would be at the bottom bar?

Comment: I can't right-click from the tablet.

Comment: Then you can hold it by touch like `Android` and drag it down to the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you go to the Start screen. You can do so by either going to the bottom left corner of the screen or by activating the Charms Bar by going to the top right corner of the screen. When you're at the Start Screen locate the app the want to uninstall and right click on it. Once you have done that a bar will come out from the bottom. The second button from the right will show the Uninstall button.

Note: Or in your case a right click would be to tap and hold the app, then drag it down.

Comment: Aha! Didn't know about the short drag down. That did the trick.

Comment: I think **Note** will be more suitable instead of **Edit** if you have not edit the post. :)

Answer (score 2):

For Mouse and Keyboard Users:

1. Right-click on the apps that you want to uninstall
2. A bar will slide up at the bottom of the screen which gives you the option to uninstall the app